# What is the Maximum and minimum value of the given expression

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

Can anyone find the maximum and the minimum value of the following expression 
$$\frac{x+1}{xy+x+1}+\frac{y+1}{yz+y+1}+\frac{z+1}{zx+z+1}$$ 
for all $x,y,z$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: what kind of numbers are $$x,y,z$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum does not exist. Try $x>-1$ and $xy+x+1\rightarrow0^+$.

The minimum does not exist. Try $x<-1$ and $xy+x+1\rightarrow0^+$.